# How to remove macvim left side menu

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

[image]

I want to know to how remove left part which I don't know how to name it using macvim. I have tried below code in `.vimrc`.

```
:set guioptions-=m  "remove menu bar
:set guioptions-=T  "remove toolbar
:set guioptions-=r  "remove right-hand scroll bar
:set guioptions-=L  "remove left-hand scroll bar
```

But the left menu still there.

Comment: What is left menu bar?

Comment: @dimeetei I have changed the statement. please let me know whether I named it right. thank you

Comment: Great, Do you have NerdTree plugins installed?

Comment: seems I have installed NerdTree

Comment: Try `:nmap <F6> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` and hit F6.

Comment: thanks. It worked!

Comment: @dimeetei  It seems that I need to learn how to use NerdTree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The side pane that you see, which is from `NerdTree`, can be toggled by mapping to a key of convenience, for example <kbd>F6</kbd> here.

```
:nnoremap <F6> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

You can use `:NERDTreeClose` to close it but I like toggling which save keystrokes.